# After WP 4.6.1 Update , Blog page started giving 500 error

Tags: theme-development, blog-page

i hope you can help me ,

So first of all , this is a theme related problem, since im not having any problems with the default wordpress themes.

So what i noticed is that after 4.6.1 update the blog page started showing only 1 post, and then , nothing , there'sno admin-bar {since im already logged in} no footer no bottom bar , nothing, after openning the console log , i see the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

And since the update was applied automatically, i don't have a backup. So , are there possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Please **[edit] your question**, and add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities that causes this error. There might be your theme is not comaptible to wordpress 4.6.1 
Please make on debug mode by writing change below lines in wp_config.php from

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and add below line to make debug log on

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

And then run your front end and go to wp-content folder, here you will find debug.log file, open this file and check error. If error is related to max execution time related then please increase max execution time of your hosting.

From this error log, try to solve error.

You can directly chat or contact also your hosting provider.